# Handle event in all nested HTML elements in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While building a table, I'm binding **onClick** handler to **td** element:

```html
<td data-person-id={person.id} onClick={this.removePerson}>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-default">
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">Remove</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

But when an event is handled, it points to **button** or **span** elements but not **td** one so it means I can't just get needed **data-person-id** attribute. How can I fix it?

Full code https://jsfiddle.net/osqbvuub/1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>
    <button 
      type="button" 
      className="btn btn-default btn-default"
      onClick={this.removePerson.bind(this, person.id)}>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">Remove</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

Let your button element handle `onClick` (otherwise you might have weird behavior like clicking outside of the button but inside of `td` triggering an event) and `bind` the id to the context.

Then, later on your `removePerson` function access `id` directly:

```
...
removePerson(id) {
  // do stuff
}
...
```